# Onclick para fechar um modal sem reload

Tags: javascript, html, modal, button, onclick

Esse button fecha um modal, mas precisa ser sem causar um reload. Há como?

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Ué é só retirar a função **window.location.reload** no `onlick` do botão.

Comment: Coloque `javascript:void(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que nesse seu botão:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```

o código:

`onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()"`

faz com que a pagina seja recarregada, você pode tirar esse evento de onclick ou então colocar para que retorne void.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button> 

onclick="javascript:void(0)"
```